# Transformation that adds data from external file

Tags: java, xml, bash, xslt

I have a transformation that parses a xml file (example below) and produces based on that wiki markup.
My input xml file for transformation looks like this:

```
 //fileA
<services xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <service>
         <name>Service1</name>
         <wsdl:operation>A1</wsdl:operation>
    </service>

    <service>
         <name>Service2</name>
         <wsdl:operation>A2</wsdl:operation>
    </service>

    ...

    <service>
         <name>ServiceN</name>
         <wsdl:operation>AN</wsdl:operation>
    </service>

 </services>
```

I would like to create xslt transformation that will parse other file that holds key-value pairs (the format may be different)

```
 //fileB
<services xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <service>
         <name>Service1</name>
         <link>http://www.mydomain.com/wsdl/Service1.html</link> 
    </service>

    <service>
         <name>Service2</name>
         <link>http://www.mydomain.com/wsdl/buy/Service2.html</link>
    </service>

    ...

    <service>
         <name>ServiceN</name>
         <link>http://www.mydomain.com/wsdl/sell/ServiceN.html</link>
    </service>

 </services>
```

and will produce xml file

```
//fileC
<services xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <service>
         <name>Service1</name>
         <wsdl:operation>A1</wsdl:operation>
         <link>http://www.mydomain.com/wsdl/Service1.html</link> 
    </service>

    <service>
         <name>Service2</name>
         <wsdl:operation>A2</wsdl:operation>
         <link>http://www.mydomain.com/wsdl/buy/Service2.html</link>
    </service>

    ...

    <service>
         <name>ServiceN</name>
         <wsdl:operation>AN</wsdl:operation>
         <link>http://www.mydomain.com/wsdl/sell/ServiceN.html</link>
    </service>

 </services>
```

is it possible? I would like to transform somehow fileA into fileC using fileB.

Comment: XSLT is great to process XML input. Since your second file is not XML, it would be easier to use a programming language (Java, C#, PHP, etc.) that could read each line, split by the `=` and generate the XML. If that's an option, add a tag for the programming language you prefer to use and edit your question.

Comment: It was only example - now file B is also a xml file.

Comment: searching for "merge xml files", I found http://stackoverflow.com/q/1510688/7552

Comment: Thanks for that post however my xml files are already generated from xslt so is there any way to add "<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="merge.xsl"?>" into one of them? So the question now should be how to add "<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="merge.xsl"?>" into xml file generated by xslt? Ok, I've found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300749/insert-xml-stylesheet-tag-with-xsl I think that is solves problem.

Comment: @glennjackman Could somebody make an answer? I would like to get this out of the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: This is 3.5 years old. I am not going to do anything about it. You're welcome to add something yourself if you care.